# Thunderbolt 3 - Thunderbolt 2 problem

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt

I have a new MacMini, OS 10.15.3 and I am trying to connect a new Presonus Quantum Thunderbolt Interface to the Mac.

The Presonus has two TB 2 connections, the Mac has TB 3 connections.

I have connected an Apple TB3 to TB2 adapter to the Mac and a 3m Delock TB2 cable from the adapter to the Presonus.

I am using LOGIC recording software and the Mac/LOGIC will not detect the Presonus.

I need your help and advice please.

Comment: I asume the Mac has a [Core i5 or better](https://www.presonus.com/products/Quantum/tech-specs) and that you have installed the latest [Universal Control v3.2.0.56558](https://www.presonus.com/products/Quantum/downloads) software.

Answer (score 1):

On the Presonus forum it appears I am not the only one with this connection problem. There are very many unhappy un-users on there...

I uninstalled and reinstalled their Universal Control software several times and tried different approaches. One thing I did discover is it is very important to open the Security and Privacy section in Mac system preferences and change the settings to allow third party software.

I also followed the advice of a contributer on the Presonus forum, advice which is not mentioned in the Presonus setup information... 
Following an install of the Universal Control software you switch off the Quantum and unplug the TB cable. You reboot, reconnect the TB cable and switch on the Quantum and it worked. Thanks for the advice and happy recording.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac has Core i7 and the correct Presonus Universal Control software installed.
Since I received your reply, I have made some headway on the problem. I reinstalled the Presonus UC software and checked the Mac Finder. The Quantum is now listed under Thunderbolt Device Tree so that's one problem sorted, thank you.
The problem I now face is trying to get the Quantum to sync with the Mac.